# isql*plus crashes in 9i when multiple user execute query simultaneously in oracle 9i

Tags: oracle

In my workplace Multiple users are using isql*plus(oracle 9i) to access single database through server url .But after some time isql*plus crashes and its services needs to started.

Its causes  a lot of  time waste and is also decreasing the productivity please help.
Sever is a desktop with 2 GB of RAM and 2.5Ghz AMD processor 
No of user 25.

1. The way database is accessed isql*plus
2. isql*plus is insatalled in pc in which main database access is provided (like proxy server ). here is the main problem and you can say isql*plus services crashes in proxy server.
3. If services runs correctly then its routed to database and database gives result to proxy server.
4. user see the result in isqlplus browser(url =ip address of proxy ).

clients make request using